# Cairo: Refilling an object(circle) and deleting it

Tags: c++, c, gtk, drawing, cairo

I'm drawing some arcs using cairo, Here's the function.

```
cairo_t* drawCircle(cairo_surface_t *container, int x, int y, int r, int cr, int cg, int   cb, int ca)
{
  cairo_t               *cairoInstance;                                                                                                                                 //Create instance
  cairoInstance = cairo_create(container);  

  cairo_set_source_rgba(cairoInstance, 0,0,1,0.5);
  cairo_arc(cairoInstance, x, y, r, 0, 2*M_PI);
  cairo_stroke_preserve(cairoInstance);
  cairo_fill(cairoInstance);


  gtk_widget_queue_draw_area(GTK_WIDGET(window), 0, 0, WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT); //Redraws the window

return cairoInstance;
}
```

First question: When I change the source_rgba later and then fill, it fills over the previous color. Is there a way to reset the fill before filling again with a different color?

Second of all, If I wanted to unrender/delete the arc/circle later on, how do I do that? I tried to use cairo_destroy but it seems to destroy the instance and not delete the actual object.

Thanks!

Comment: What does "reset the fill" mean?

Comment: Remove the previous color, so basically, a 100% transparent circle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cairo uses the stencil/paint model so drawing is (usually) done on top of the existing image<sub>1</sub>.

It doesn't maintain layers or objects. Just like drawing on paper, you can't *move* or *modify* the circle after its drawn. It has become a pattern in the pixmap.

To *delete* the circle, fill the whole image with the original background (`cairo_set_source_rgb(cr, 1, 1, 1); cairo_paint(cr)`), and redraw everything *except* the circle.

<sub>1. You can change the raster opcode to do other types of compositing.</sub>

Comment: How do you suggest I fill the image with the original background?

Comment: Background is an image. So basically, I'm drawing some circles over an image.

Comment: Whatever you did to draw the image, do that again. `cairo_set_source_surface(cr, surf, 0, 0); cairo_paint(cr);` ?

Comment: It draws over the previous image, so looks like the drawing area needs to be redefined?

Comment: Edit: Image needs to be recreated since the preexisting one has been altered with other elements. so what I did exactly is:

        mainImage = cairo_image_surface_create_from_png(IMAGE_PATH);
 cairo_set_source_surface(element, mainImage, 0, 0);
 cairo_paint(element);

Where element is just any element(cairo_t) on the image. (A circle, here)And then redraw the area.