# How to erace (delete) the filled cairo shape?

Tags: c++, gtk, drawable, cairo, gtkmm

I want to paint a rectangle to select the area according to mouse coordinates. So, the rectangle should be created and deleted every frame (the if statement below executes every frame). I was trying to call these functions, but nothing happened - shapes were painting one above another.

```
cairo_surface_destroy(surface);

cairo_destroy(cr);



    if (xevent.type == MotionNotify && isPressed == true)
    {
      int tmp_x = xevent.xmotion.x_root;
      int tmp_y = xevent.xmotion.y_root;

      int scr = DefaultScreen(xdisplay);
      cairo_surface_t *surface = cairo_xlib_surface_create(xdisplay, xroot, DefaultVisual(xdisplay, scr), DisplayWidth(xdisplay, scr), DisplayHeight(xdisplay, scr));
      cairo_t *cr = cairo_create(surface);

      cairo_rectangle(cr, init_x, init_y, tmp_x - init_x, tmp_y - init_y); /* set rectangle */
      cairo_set_source_rgba(cr, 0.3, 0.4, 0.6, 0.1);                       /* set fill color */
      cairo_fill(cr);
      cairo_destroy(cr);
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cairo: Refilling an object(circle) and deleting it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16256613/cairo-refilling-an-objectcircle-and-deleting-it)

Comment: No, it just fills all my screen with a color